# How can I update a ValueQuerySet with another ValueQuerySet?

Tags: python, django

I have the following two ValueQuerySets from Django.

```
dict1 = [{'user': 1, 'total_bookmarked': 2}, {'user': 2, 'total_bookmarked': 3}]

dict2 = [{'user': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'user': 2, 'name': 'Paula'}]
```

How can I merge the two ValueQuerySet so that I can get the following:

```
dict3 = [{'user': 1, 'name': 'Joe', 'total_bookmarked':2}, {'user': 2, 'name': 'Paula', 'total_bookmarked': 3}]
```

How would I do this?  I have thought about converting these back into a Python list of dictionaries, but I'm not sure exactly how to approach it even it that works.

Comment: Is it not possible to get this all in one query? It would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would first suggest you try to see if you can get this in one query because its more efficient. But if you want to **update the first list with the second list**, and they are both in the same order:

```
list1 = [{'user': 1, 'total_bookmarked': 2}, {'user': 2, 'total_bookmarked': 3}]
list2 = [{'user': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'user': 2, 'name': 'Paula'}]

for a,b in zip(list1, list2):
    a.update(b)
```

You can further improve the efficiency if they are very large lists by using `izip`

```
from itertools import izip

for a,b in izip(list1, list2):
    a.update(b)
```

And if for some reason they are not both already sorted by user:

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1.sort(key=itemgetter('user'))
list2.sort(key=itemgetter('user'))
```

I would avoid a solution that uses nested for-loops, as it won't be as efficient.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the updated list of dicts is in list1

Comment: @PaulSeeb: I already said that it would update the first list with the second.

Answer (score 0):

If they were just unordered lists or dictionaries it would be

```
list1 = [{'user': 1, 'total_bookmarked': 2}, {'user': 2, 'total_bookmarked': 3}]
list2 = [{'user': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'user': 2, 'name': 'Paula'}]
list3 = []
for d1 in list1:
    for d2 in list2: 
        if d1['user'] == d2['user']:
            d3 = dict(d1.items()+d2.items()
            list3.append(d3)
            break
        else:
            continue
```

There is a much better way if your lists are ordered by user

```
list1 = [{'user': 1, 'total_bookmarked': 2}, {'user': 2, 'total_bookmarked': 3}]
list2 = [{'user': 1, 'name': 'Joe'}, {'user': 2, 'name': 'Paula'}]

list3 = [dict(d1.items()+d2.items()) for (d1, d2) in zip(list1,list2)]
```